# How to check if an Excel document cell is being edited

Tags: c#, excel

In C#, how can I check if within an Excel document there's a general selected cell and this cell is also active for editing its value?

Manually, in Excel you can select a single cell by a single left click; you can start editing it by double clicking the cell... the 2nd situation is what I need to check programmatically.

NEW EDIT: The problem is that if a cell is being edited, then Excel is stuck and a crash occurs accessing the Active Workbook. So, if I can previously determine if cell is being edited I don't proceed accessing the workbook.

Comment: Are you saying you want to intercept the "edit" event? In what context does your code run?

Comment: Hi Simon, please look at the 'new edit' in the question, thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to edit a worksheet while it is open by Excel and somebody is working on it? Is it possible?

Comment: You may find [this similar msdn question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3333e18b-cef3-4d78-b47a-6916a1b2d84c/excel-edit-mode?forum=isvvba) useful

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie it works! Please copy your comment and use it as answer, then I will post the updated c# code version. Thanks

Comment: Good to hear! I don't actually know which part worked for you - it's probably best if you answer the question yourself, as I only provided a hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [SimonMᶜKenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622391/simon-m%E1%B6%9Ckenzie) suggested, I found a trick to solve my problem by following [this document](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20267/Determining-if-Excel-is-in-Edit-mode)...

The solution I've implemented is this one:

```
 bool IsCellBeingEdited(Excel.Application excelApp)
 {
   CORE.CommandBarControl cbc = excelApp.CommandBars.FindControl(1, 18, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing);
   return cbc != null && !cbc.Enabled;
 }
```